# Adding Kendo UI to an existing MVC 4 project

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a question about Kendo UI. I have an existing MVC4 project in which I wanted to use some of the Kendo extensions, namely the Editor. Currently the project uses jqWidgets as a UI framework.

I opened VS 2012, loaded the project and used the Telerik menu to add references to Kendo in the project. The wizard added all the necessary references and made changes to the web.config files. So far so good. However, I have two problems:

- When I try to use the Kendo Html Helper I do not have intellisense and the Kendo is underlined saying that the HtmlHelper does not have a definition for 'Kendo'. I have `<add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />` in both, my main web.config as well as in the web.config in the Views folder. Strangely enough, when I run the site, I do not get an error, but the editor does not load its initial content and if I try to interract with it, I get the following error: (my second question)
- `TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e`  -  I am guessing that somewhere in the site, There is a conflict that couses this error, but I cannot find it. Here is how I load all the JS files in my _Layout.cshtml:

```razor
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.all.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/kendo.modernizr.custom.js")
```

I am not sure if the problems are related. My jQuery version is 1.9.1 and I am using the latest Kendo version (2013.2.918.340)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is how I use the editor in the View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Editor()
                      .Name("editor")
                      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 700px; height: 400px" })
                      .Value(@<text>

                            <p>
                                Some text
                            </p>

                      </text>)
                      .ImageBrowser(imageBrowser => imageBrowser
                        .Image("~/Content/UserFiles/Images/{0}")    
                        .Read("Read", "ImageBrowser")
                        .Create("Create", "ImageBrowser")
                        .Destroy("Destroy", "ImageBrowser")
                        .Upload("Upload", "ImageBrowser")
                        .Thumbnail("Thumbnail", "ImageBrowser"))
                )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the first problem is to add namespace reference only to the `web.config` file in the `Views` folder. There is no need to add it to the root `web.config`. After that restart Visual Studio and reload your project. Everything should be fine and intellisense should work.

As for the second problem, this is hard to guess. Could you show your code where you are loading the contents into HTML editor?

Comment: Thank you Husein. I did not realize that the VS has to be restarted for the namespace changes to take effect. Below is how I use the editor.

Comment: I dont know if this makes a difference, but the Editor is hosted in a jqWidgets window control. Do you think that using both frameworks at the same time might be the problem?

Comment: As I suspected, as soon as I took the editor out of the jqWidgets' window control, everything started working properly.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad I was at least partially helpful to you :-)